# Change selected element with backend data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select, element

I have a select element populating with object array in my controller.

```
$scope.CompanyType = [{ value: 0, name: 'Satıcı' }, {value:1,name:'Üretici'}];
```

Whenever i get data from backend server i want to change selected item in select element according to the data i retrived from server.

Comment: Show us what you tried?

Comment: Now i populate my select element with this object array. and in html part my code is like this <select ng-model="SelectedCompanyType" ng-options="_CompanyType as _CompanyType.name for _CompanyType in CompanyType " id="CompanyTypeSelect">. when i get data from server i want to change the active select option according to data i get from server. my controller is like this $scope.ShowCompnyDetail = function (_id) {
        $scope.mode = 'edit';
        $scope.Company = CompnyService.get({ Id: _id });
        $scope.SelectedCompanyType = $Scope.CompanyType[Company.Type];